# Incremental search in libreoffice-calc

Tags: search, libreoffice-calc

Is there an incremental search feature in libreoffice-calc similar to that one in emacs or firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like in Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> in LibreOffice calc 3.4.4 opens a search toolbar near the bottom of the screen. The toolbar has `Find Next` and `Find Previous` buttons.

.

Comment: Thanks, I installed version 3.4.4 and tried it, but it doesn't seem to be real [incremental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search), you have to press enter before it begins to search... Perhaps there is a hidden option to make it incremental?

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure what you meant by incremental.